# Telegram create poll and read poll results

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

was able to write the following code to create a poll in Telegram.  Most important for my question is that I'm using
[https://api.telegram.org/bot{telegram_api}/sendpoll](https://api.telegram.org/bot%7Btelegram_api%7D/sendpoll)
to create the poll, but I can't figure out how the read the poll. Been trying with
[https://api.telegram.org/bot{telegram_api}/pollAnswer](https://api.telegram.org/bot%7Btelegram_api%7D/pollAnswer)
and in the params I pass the message_id I receive from sending the poll. But keep getting 404 errors.

Browsing through the API docs, I can't find the correct URL I have to call. ChatGPT tells me to use getPoll but can't find other references for it. But then again I also can't find any reference to "sendPoll" but that does work.

The documentation on https://core.telegram.org/api/poll doesn't make sense to me, I don't know how to translate those blocks to api calls.

I know there is python-telegram-bot but that seems so overly complicated for the small thing I want to do.

Anyone an example how to read a telegram poll?

```
def new_telegram_poll():
"""Send a poll to telegram in a specific group"""
telegram_api, telegram_channel_id = get_telegram_creds()

baseurl = (
    f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{telegram_api}/sendpoll"
    )

parameters={
    "chat_id": telegram_channel_id,
    "question":"This is a poll",
    "options":json.dumps([
            'option1',
            'option2',
            'option3'
            ]),
    "is_anonymous":False,
    "allows_multiple_answers":False,
    "type":"regular",
}

response = requests.get(url=baseurl,data=parameters, timeout=15)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print("Error while posting to telegram API %s", response.status_code)
    sys.exit()
else:
    message_id = response.json()['result']['message_id']
    poll_id = response.json()['result']['poll']['id']
    return message_id, poll_id
```

Answer (score 3):

Retrieving poll answers do not require a separate API route, just as every other 'message' [they're retrieved](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates) by calling the [`getUpdates`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) route

If you use [Webhooks](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates), they will replace the `getUpdates` route.

For example, when calling `getUpdates`, and somebody voted on a poll, a update object will look something like this:

```json
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "update_id": 97327414,
            "poll": {
                "id": "5456270751402523521",
                "question": "Foo Bar ?",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "text": "yes",
                        "voter_count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "no",
                        "voter_count": 0
                    }
                ],
                "total_voter_count": 1,
                "is_closed": false,
                "is_anonymous": true,
                "type": "regular",
                "allows_multiple_answers": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Regaring your 'documentation' link, you're referencing the [telegram core](https://core.telegram.org/), no need to look into that, you need the [Telegram Bot API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).

Comment: When I create the poll, I see it in my telegram app. Then I vote on the poll and then run:
    baseurl = (
        f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{telegram_api}/getUpdates"
        )
    response  = requests.get( baseurl, timeout=15)
The only response is:
{'ok': True, 'result': []}

According to the getUpdates, I shouldn't have to pass chat_id or message_id, do I?

Comment: Does it matter that in the Telegram App, it shows as a bot in which all the polls arrive? It is not a group / channel I'm sending the polls to if I understand correctly.

Comment: No thats fine as it is. Are you sure no other script is running that is clearing the getUpdates? Not sure what you mean by the send comment, but I assumed you're sending the poll to a normal chat.

Comment: "Are you sure no other script is clearing the getUpdates?"
Well, maybe I'm confused, but I'm sending the poll using https://api.telegram.org/bot{telegram_api}/sendpoll to a supergroup. After sending my script is on hold waiting for keypress.

I have my telegram desktop client open. In the group I see "Telegram Home Ass" as the sender of the poll, which is the name of the bot. Then as user "Gabrie" viewing the desktop app, I click on a poll answer.  

Then I do a keypress in my script to call the https://api.telegram.org/bot{telegram_api}/getUpdates. Which returns only OK.